# Synchronising text in word

Tags: windows

I have a word template with a table of business cards. These card are diferent text is a table. When I edit the text in one table it automaticly updates the text in the other tables. I tried to figure out how I works but unsuccesful. The template is called "Big wave business cards" provided by "Microsoft Corporation".

I tried 'copy' and 'Paste Special..'.